# To fazendo um formulario em php e preciso atualizar o DB se um usuario fazer alterações nos dados

Tags: php

Eu sei fazer isso por if else, mas tenho 8 campos onde pode ter apenas 1,2,3... campos em branco e tenho que verificar se o campo esta em branco e se não estiver atualizar no DB, queria saber se tem jeito mais fácil.

```
<form  action="alteraroficioC1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr><th>Nº</th><td><?php echo $idget ?></td><td>Alterar para: </td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><th>Data</th><td><?php echo $dataof ?></td><td><input type="input" name="data" id="<?php echo $idInput; ?>" onkeyup="mascaraData(<?php echo $idInput; ?>);" maxlength="10" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" /></td><td><input type="image" src="../images/save_01_16x16.png" name="id" value="<?php echo $manid; ?>"></td></tr>
            <tr><th>Solicitado por</th><td><?php echo $solicitado ?></td><td><input type="text" name="nomePor" </td><td><input type="image" src="../images/save_01_16x16.png" name="id" value="<?php echo $manid; ?>"></td></tr>
            <tr><th>Destino/Unidade</th><td><?php echo $destino ?></td><td><input type="text" name="nomePor" </td><td><input type="image" src="../images/save_01_16x16.png" name="id" value="<?php echo $manid; ?>"></td></tr>
            <tr><th>Setor</th><td><?php echo $setor ?></td><td><input type="text" name="nomePor" </td><td><input type="image" src="../images/save_01_16x16.png" name="id" value="<?php echo $manid; ?>"></td></tr>
            <tr><th>Para/Pessoa</th><td><?php echo $nomepara ?></td><td><input type="text" name="nomePor" </td><td><input type="image" src="../images/save_01_16x16.png" name="id" value="<?php echo $manid; ?>"></td></tr></tr>
            <tr><th>Nome</th><td><?php echo $nome ?></td><td><input type="text" name="nomePor" </td><td><input type="image" src="../images/save_01_16x16.png" name="id" value="<?php echo $manid; ?>"></td></tr></tr>
            <tr><th>Assunto</th><td><?php echo $assunto ?></td><td><input type="text" name="nomePor" </td><td><input type="image" src="../images/save_01_16x16.png" name="id" value="<?php echo $manid; ?>"></td></tr></tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="idd" value="<?php echo $idget; ?>"/> <? // para redirect()?>
        </form>
```

este eh o formulario que sai com um layout assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá um exemplo de código na pergunta, é um array ou variáveis 'soltas'?

Comment: coloquei exemplos, mas ja cheguei numa solução para meu problema, obrigado.

Comment: Já resolvi o problema utilizando o recurso default do html.

Comment: Usou o `require` ?

Comment: Alguma das respostas solucionou o teu problema? Nesse caso podes marcar como aceite. Senão podes dar uma resposta como fizeste mas explicando como resolveste o problema. Assim como está é demasiado curto para ser uma resposta e não ajudará outros que possam ter o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2):

Para identificar quais elementos de um array estão vazios, uma maneira é combinar as funções `array_keys()`, `array_filter()`, `array_flipper()` e `array_diff()`.

`array_keys()` obtém as chaves(nome, email etc) do 'array de dados' para informar o usuário quais campos foram deixados em branco posteriormente.

`array_filter()` verifica se cada elemento do array passado está vazio se sim ele não é adicionado ao novo array.

`array_diff()` faz a diferença do array de chaves que sempre estará preenchido com o array de dados(`$arr`) ou seja se algum elemento em `$invalidos` significa que algum campos veio em branco caso contario significa que `$arr` e `$keys` são iguais e um array com zero elementos será gerado, o `count()` faz essa verificação.

```
$arr = ['nome' => '', 'idade' => 0, 'email' => ''];
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$arr = array_filter($arr);
$invalidos = array_diff($keys, array_flip($arr));

if(count($invalidos) > 0){
    'Campos em branco: '. implode(', ', $invalido);
}else{
    echo 'Tudo certo';
}
```